# ERROR: PHP XML extension missing. To continue, install PHP XML extension, then restart web server While Installing OpenEMR

Tags: php, xml

IHi all,

I'm facing an issue while setting up OpenEMR on my Ubuntu 20.04.06 system with PHP 8.2. I've installed the PHP XML extension using sudo apt-get install php8.2-xml, and it shows as the newest version already. However, when I access the OpenEMR setup page, it still says that PHP XML is missing.

I have multiple PHP versions (5.6, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 8.0, 8.1, 8.2) on my system, and recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 20.04.06 and PHP from 7.4 to 8.2 to meet the OpenEMR 7.0.1 requirements.

I have tried restarting Apache and PHP-FPM with sudo service apache2 restart and sudo service php8.2-fpm restart, but the issue persists.

Can anyone help me identify why the OpenEMR setup is not detecting the PHP XML extension, even though it's installed? Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please add the commands in their order you executed them with their relevant output to the question. While your description is clearly readable and good to follow, the concrete commands you had in use are not visible so there is very little that can be said about your problem The only program output that is visible from your question is that of OpenEMR and that says that that PHP XML is missing.

Comment: Additionally the upgrade you talk about could be the problem. Get another box and install Ubuntu 20.04.06 LTS from scratch with the software in question. Then let us know if you were able to get the configuration to run on that (temporary) system with your commands.